# IBM Watson VIsual Recognition - ERROR: excessive number of concurrent HTTP connections

Tags: java, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

Having trouble adding a class to one of my custom classifiers using Visual Recognition, when executing the task I get the below error:

> status: 500, error: If you are seeing this message, you are likely making an excessive number of concurrent HTTP connections to this service.  Please check the concurrency limits for your assigned service tier.

Does anyone know what this means or where I can manage my "concurrency limits"?

Edit: This is the code I'm using to make the call of adding a new class.

```
File positiveImgs = new File(".../" + className + ".zip");

ClassifierOptions options = 
   new ClassifierOptions.Builder().addClass(className, positiveImgs).build();

VisualClassifier result;
result = service.updateClassifier(classifierID, options).execute();

System.out.println(result);
```

Thanks

Comment: What part of the message is unclear? How does the message relate to your use of concurrent sessions? Are you forgetting to close old sessions and/or creating a new session for each request?  The question is not answerable given the information you've provided.

Comment: @JimGarrison I've updated the original post with a snippet of my code, what's unclear is that I don't know why I'm getting the error. Don't think I'm forgetting to close old sessions/or don't know how to close them. This is the first thing I'm trying to run when I run my app. IBM'sdocumentation for the java-sdk isn't thorough and I can't seem to find any reference for 'concurrency' limits anywhere.

Comment: The issue will be where you instantiate `service`.  I have no idea how Watson VR works, but you need to examine your code around establishing the connection to make sure you're not creating a new connection on each request.

Answer (score 2):

This was resolved, it looks like it was an issue with IBM Watson services today which was resolved by IBM.

Comment: That is correct - sorry for the inconvenience, @ItsJose