# Watson: Error message - excessive number of https connections to this service

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I'm working with the Watson Visual Recognition service using Cygwin and curl. I am submitting a zip of images to create a new class in an existing classifier, however I am getting this response:

> "If you are seeing this message, you are likely making an excessive number of concurrent HTTP connections to this service. Please check the concurrency limits for your assigned service tier."

I have added a card to my account so I am now on the pay-as-you-go tier.  Other questions like this on Stack Overflow have suggested an internal service error.  I have checked Watson's status which shows no problems.

The other thing I should mention is that I am not an experienced command line user, - I made some code mistakes causing cygwin to do hang, so I closed the Cygwin windows on these occasions, without explicitly closing the https connection, - might this be contributing? How can I do this?

---

This question is similar to the one I am asking, however the difference is that I have checked the service status which appears to be ok: [IBM Watson VIsual Recognition - ERROR: excessive number of concurrent HTTP connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900391/ibm-watson-visual-recognition-error-excessive-number-of-concurrent-http-conne?rq=1)

Comment: It may be that you have hit an internal issue that is not reflected in the service status.  I would suggest raising a Blumix upport ticket.  However, It would be useful if you can add to this question some more information, e.g. The curl command line you are using, the number and size of the images in the zip file and the size of the zip file.

Comment: Thank you, it seems as though it was a temporary issue as works okay now. Out of curiosity, is there a need to explicitly close https connections in CURL do you know?

Comment: When the curl statement finishes running, the connection should be closed automatically.  Howver, this may not be the case if you are going via a proxy server.